# .Net Core authorize authenticated users with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi,

We have a .Net Core 2.0 app, with Azure AD authentication.
At the moment we have some users associated with the app that have been given a role for the app in the Azure AD, and are using policies to check authorisation. Due business requirements we want to open the app to any user on the company, so we only need to check that the user is authenticated.

As an experienced C# developer, I went to the controller that had the following code

```
[Authorize(Policy = PolicyNames.RequireLinecardsUser)]
        public class LinecardController : Controller
        {
            //controller code here
        }
```

and changed it to this

```
    [Authorize]
        public class LinecardController : Controller
        {
            //controller code here
        }
```

and for may user, that still has the role of LinecardUser, it works. it can access the app (the main entry point is inside that controller). But when we tested it with a user that does not have a role in the app, it gets an access denied exception.

So next step we went into startup, and removed the authorisation configurations ( it only had 2 now unused policies).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                try
                {
                    services.AddDbContext(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LinecardsContext"), opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging());
                    });
                    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                        {
                            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultForbidScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        })
                        .AddCookie(options =>
                        {
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied/";
                            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
                        })
                        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                        {
                            configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
                        });

                   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                        {
                            options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.RequireLinecardsUser,
                                      policy =>
                                      {
                                              policy.AddRequirements(new LinecardsWebUserRequirement()); 
                                              policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); // Adds DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement 
                                                                                 // By adding the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, if an authenticated
                                                                                 // user is not in the appropriate role, they will be redirected to a "forbidden" page.
                                              policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                                      });

                            options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.RequireLinecardsAdmin,
                                        policy =>
                                        {
                                            policy.AddRequirements(new LinecardsWebAdminRequirement());
                                            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); // Adds DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement 
                                                                               // By adding the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, if an authenticated
                                                                               // user is not in the appropriate role, they will be redirected to a "forbidden" page.
                                                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                                        });
                        });

                    services.AddScoped();

                    services.RegisterTypes();

                    services.AddReact();

                    services.AddAutoMapper();

                    services.Configure(x => x.ValueCountLimit = 100000);
                    services.AddMvc();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "Error happened on configuring services");
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

That means that in the previous code we removed the services.AddAuthentication(); block. Same result, users that have roles can access the app, users that don't cannot. (tried with the browser in anonymous mode too, to make sure no caching problems were in action here).

Finally we tried to change the RequireLinecardsUser policy, so it didn't have the policy.AddRequirements(new LinecardsWebUserRequirement()); line (and changed the controller to the original authorization line with the policy.
Once again, same results, works fine for me, access denied for users that don't have a role.

Am I missing something obvious? Something that changed in Core 2.0? Something Azure related?
Because every documentation that I found says that the [Authorize] annotation without any arguments should work and intended, and only verify that user is authenticated before allowing the code to procede...

As some of you may have noticed the app has a react frontend that I haven't touched, feel free to point any problems that may be related with that.

PPS: Sorry if the formatting is not up to standard, but it's my first question

Answer (score 0):

After some more tests with this app, an exception pointed to Azure being the culprit for this.
On the app properties in Azure there is an option asking "User assignment required?". That particular setting was set to yes for this app.
Changing it to no solved the problem.